# Error on API Call in background refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I am using

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) 
{

}.
```

the request is called every 20 seconds iam getting `error` 500.Can someone please help me to solve this.

Comment: First, ensure you have the Transport Security Settings properly set ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http ). After that, error 500 is an internal server error, so the issue is server side, could be an error related to missing or wrong parameters sent to the server, or stg else on the server too

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the way you're constructing the request.  You'll have to post more code before we can help in any meaningful way.  Also, why aren't you using NSURLSession?  Are you still supporting 10.8/iOS 6?